# When to use Adobe AIR vs Regular Desktop Apps eg. VB, C# 

Tags: air

i wonder what isit that Adobe AIR is better to use compared with say VB/C# apps.

- i dont think Adobe AIR is faster/more efficent right?
- DB wise. SqlLite vs MSSQL Express, both are free, 1 is open source, but MSSQL is more powerful? isit faster?
- in AIR u still need to create 1 app for web and another for windows applications? so it will still be similar to using Windows Apps vs Web Apps. u probably can share classes/library's?

Answer (score 1):

I've done a little work w/ Air and I'll give you a few reasons to consider it:

1. it's portable, the underlying foundation is webkit and flash, so you can create a flash app or a web app and deliver it to the desktop and if you are a web programmer you will know exactly what to do
2. distribution and update of your software is going to be a breeze, Air has done a great job of building out the mechanics/experience of updating an application
3. its super web app platform with strong sandbox protections for the user
4. generally performance is pretty good the jit compiler for flash is impressive, but one thing to be aware of - if your app is on the larger side and you do need to pay attention to memory use.

Answer (score 0):

I think scalability would be a good reason. Your application would run "in the clouds" and all users would share the same data. It's easier to update the application since you only update the cloud, not every single user. The same applies to the data used by the application, which you can keep up-to-date for everyone, all the time.

It's not about power, though. It's more about having 50.000 people use your application all at the same time, keeping them up-to-date all the time with the most recent version of your application. (Preferably bug-free.) It does have it's advantages, although there are a few problems linked to this technique too. But in general this depends on the type of application that you're building.

Comment: i am abit confused. why are you talking abt cloud? i thought AIR is still a desktop app where users have to install? if i use a DB it will probably be a local 1 for speed, SqlLite is only local i think.

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a large internet based service which uses AIR for our desktop implementation. It is a great multi-platform environment.

However painful it is to say: nobody chooses to use AIR over native apps, Usually the decision is down to time and team skills (why hire 3/4 developers when you can have 1?).

It is easier to have a single development environment than try to port code to C#, Objective-C and c++. However those native OS technologies will always out-perform AIR. AIR performance on OSX is particularly prevalent.

So in your particular case you have a web application that you want to bring to the desktop, You would have to maintain 2 applications (1 web, 1 AIR), though if you went the native route you'd have to support 4 separate applications (1 each for each platform)

You could probably only share code in the abstract sense, Say have your web application provide an API for each app to interface with. Though you'd still need to maintain each apps code library.